# Unable to boot from any USB stick [ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, live-usb, boot-repair

I am unable to boot from any USB stick on my laptop how can that be?

1. I decided to format my Lenovo laptop and create 2 partition and a SWAP space on my HD
2. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on one of the partitions
3. I realized that I should have had Windows 10 installed before ubuntu (the opposite would not work)
4. I made a bootable USB stick from a Windows 10 ISO file on a different computer (win OS) to format the computer again and Install Windows 10
5. Started my laptop holding Fn+f12 gives me 4 options [Normal boot, BIOS Setup, Boot menu, System Recovery] selecting ANY of them will bring me to the Boot menu
6. The boot menu only shows me 3 options [Ubuntu, recovery mode, Advanced UEFI setting]

I am still unable to boot my Windows 10 bootable USB (I also tried with an Ubuntu Bootable USB, which also does not show at boot menu) on my Ubuntu 22.04 system

Does anybody know how to force my computer to boot from USB in order to do a fresh install of a dual OS system?

- [Boot repair logs](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tzVpPZsPyP/)

Comment: What’s in ‘Advanced uefi settings’ if you choose that?

Comment: The third option is actually UEFI firmware setting, and it opens the BIOS setup

Comment: I am now trying to boot my windows USB bootable from the Grub terminal

Comment: Are you sure that your USB drives (with Windows and Ubuntu) are bootable? Can you boot into another computer? How did you create them? Which tool/method did you use? Did you check that the iso file is good (correctly downloaded)?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem before.

1. Disconnect the cable to the hard drive.
2. Start you laptop, and press the correct key to enter the UEFI setup utility.
3. Set the Ubuntu installation USB as the first item in the boot sequence.
4. Reconnect the cable to the hard drive.

Now when you boot with the USB inserted it will boot to the Ubuntu installer.